# What is a good book about math history?

Tags: reference-request, math-history

Which is a good book on math History?

I want to give it as a gift to a mathematician.

Comment: Do you know what type of things interest them? What is their area?  Are you looking for a general book, or perhaps a biography of a particular mathematician?  Some more information always helps.

Comment: Maybe this thread helps: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/31058/

Comment: "God created the integers", a collection of translations of classic texts assembled by Stephen Hawking (or published under his name, anyway), is good in my view.  (At least, I am a mathematician who received it as a gift from a family member one Christmas, and I was very pleased to get it.)

Comment: I had two copies of an  book on the history of computers and the effects of computers on our lives. I eventually just gave the extra copy to a computer science Ph.D. student, guy who played soccer with me. He said "You're giving this to ME?" meaning that there was little chance a book I had picked out in his topic had much to tell him. So bear that in mind. Something in the nature of a diversion might be better, and less likely to already be owned.

Answer (score 8):

Though not strictly a history book, [The Princeton Companion to Mathematics](http://press.princeton.edu/titles/8350.html) is a book I'd like to get as a gift but probably wouldn't buy.

Comment: Really? I bought myself a copy, as did at least one other math person I know. Totally worth the price.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan, sure, the book *is* totally worth the price.

Comment: I bought it. But I probably wouldn't have except that right after it came out I happened to have a hundred dollars worth of miscellaneous coins which I brought to the bank, so it felt like free money.

Answer (score 4):

> > "Mathematics and its History", by John Stillwell.

[http://www.amazon.com/Mathematics-Its-History-Undergraduate-Texts/dp/144196052X](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/144196052X)

> > "Men of mathematics", by Eric Temple bell- awesome set of biographies of mathematicians from Archimedes to Poincare.

http://www.archive.org/details/MenOfMathematics

> > Leonard Dickson's "History of number theory".

http://www.archive.org/details/historyoftheoryo01dick

> > "A beautiful mind" by Sylvia Nasar, a biography of John Nash, but gives VERY good glimpses of Math and its History esp. during 20th century.

[http://www.amazon.com/Beautiful-Mind-Mathematical-Genius-Laureate/dp/0743224574](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0743224574)

Comment: Some of the stuff in Bell's work is nice, but a bit embellished in places. The section on Galois is particularly notorious...

Comment: yes, that's true. I included it particularly because of the passion with which he writes.

Answer (score 4):

I enjoyed reading the biographies of Hilbert and Courant by Constance Reid very much.

Answer (score 2):

I read [Journey Through Genius](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/014014739X) a while ago and I absolutely loved it. Highly recommended.

Comment: The average user review is pretty high on Amazon. This is a must read for all Mathematics lovers.

Answer (score 2):

[Mathematics in Historical Context](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0883855704)